# odoo 14 ,customer in payment (due date look in group)

Tags: odoo-14

Invoicing > Customers > Payments

Payments > group by > Due Date

why happened ,show "undefined".
How to solve "undefined"?

Please, Tell me

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

account.payment model is delegated inherit the account.move so its inherited all fields of account.move and one of them (Due Date (invoice_date_due)) and this field used in Customer invoice/Vendor Bills but its not used when you create/register a payment so it will be always empty for the payment.

In general: The due date set in invoices to indicate when the payment is expected so it will not mean anything in the payment.